# Send shortcut key combination to another application

Tags: c#

I want to send a shortcut key combination (e.g., Ctrl+B) to another application, but the following code is not working:

```
SetForegroundWindow(NowHandle);
SendKeys.Send("^B");
```

Why does it not work? How can I send Ctrl+B to another application?

Answer (score 0):

It will work if the other application has the focus at the moment that you call Sendkeys. So, first set the input focus to the application you want to send keystrokes to, then use SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is running as an administrator, make sure you run your code/app as an administrator as well.